# How to push a UIViewController from appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (say A). On the click of a button in the `UIViewController`(A), I load a `UIWebView`. On click of a component in the `UIWebView`, I need to push the `UIViewController`(A) once again. But I am handling the click event in the webview inside the appdelegate class. How will I push the `UIViewController` from the appdelegate class.

The click of a component in the `UIWebView` is handled by

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
}
```

in the appdelegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have a reference to your main window and having a NavigationController onscreen, this should do fine: (iOS 4 required)

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: self.window.rootViewController doesn't have pushViewController method

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to push a view controller from app delegate

Comment: Still the new viewController is not pushed.

Comment: The problem was that I had a presentModalViewController in the stack and I was pushing the new viewController under the presentModalViewController.
So I did the following

`UINavigationController *navigationController =(UINavigationController *) self.navigationController.presentedViewController;
                    
[navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`